# `noexcept` specifier for getters and setters

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class A {
    public:
        void SetInteger(const int val) noexcept { integerMember = val; }
        void SetString(const std::string& val) { stringMember = val; }
        int GetInteger() const noexcept { return integerMember; }
        std::string GetString() const { return stringMember; }

    private:
        int integerMember;
        std::string stringMember;
}
```

Using `noexcept` for integral types and pointers seems for me pretty obvious.

But what are recommendations in case of not integral types like classes and structures that do not throw exceptions in constructor/copy-constructor and constructors of their parts explicitly (meaning using `throw` in constructor body)?

Comment: To not have getters and setters in the first place :')

Comment: @GillBates, what is an appropriate alternative?

Comment: What is the reason for having them in the first place? The common excuse is "encapsulation", but you have none if both of your set and get methods are public.

Comment: Since none of the constructors throw promising the compiler that your method doesn't throw is in the worst case not going to change anything, in the best case it will gain you speed by optimizations.

Comment: @Alex Getters and setters often mean that you violate the [Law Of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: ... or, as I like to call it, the law of dementia.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `noexcept` specifiers for functions which may throw (unless you're prepared to have your code call `std::terminate()`). Explicit `throw` specifiers are deprecated, so don't rely on them, rather use the [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept). For example

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  T m_datum;
public:
  Foo& SetDatum(T const&x) noexcept(noexcept(m_datum=x))
  {
    m_datum = x;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: I've seen `m_` and `_`, but `_m_`?? :o

Comment: @BartoszKP It is just another step until the one true `_m_e_m_b_e_r_` prefix arrives.  All will dreference it, and despair.

Comment: @T.C. sorry, should have checked it. The edited version compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of special member functions, `noexcept` is not *that* useful. But if you want it:

```
void SetString(const std::string& val) 
         noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<std::string>::value) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First way for getter:

```
const std::string& GetString() const noexcept {return stringMember; }
```

Second way is for setter:

```
void SetString(std::string&& val) noexcept {
    swap(stringMember, val);
}
```